# How to convert Php foreach to Twig?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, twig

I'm using CodeIgniter with Twig, i'm trying to integrate FullCalendar 
I got the librerary form [Here](https://github.com/jamelbaz/FullCalendar-BS3-PHP-MySQL) , my problem is with this line - in the Index.php file :

```
events: [
    <?php foreach($events as $event):
        $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
        $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
        if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
            $start = $start[0];
        }else{
            $start = $event['start'];
        }
        if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
            $end = $end[0];
        }else{
            $end = $event['end'];
        }
    ?>
        {
            id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
            title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
            start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
            end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
            color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
        },
    <?php endforeach; ?>
]
```

Since i'm using Twig - i can't translate this part into twig, i've tried :

```
events: [
    {
        {% for res in events_from_db %}
        id : "{{ res.id}}",
        title : "{{ res.title}}",
        start : "{{ res.start}}",
        end : "{{ res.end}}",
        color : "{{ res.color}}",
        {% endfor %}
    }
]
```

But it's getting only the last key of the Array.... So i figure - why not simply insert the array directly - So i did this:

```
var events_from_db = '{{ events_from_db|json_encode|raw }}';

var json_res = JSON.parse(events_from_db);
events_res = [];
$.each(json_res, function (k,v) {
    events_res.push(v);
});

events: [
    events_res
]
```

But it didn't worked either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop should be outside the JS brackets:

```
{% for res in events_from_db %}
    {
        id : "{{ res.id}}",
        title : "{{ res.title}}",
        start : "{{ res.start}}",
        end : "{{ res.end}}",
        color : "{{ res.color}}",
    },
{% endfor %}
```